# I want to know how to write pseudo code of a program for Raptor programming language?

Tags: c++, arrays, pseudocode, file-handling, raptor

I have a program and i have to write its pseudo code and it will be implemented in Raptor Language. I am confused that how to write its pseudo code. I know how to write pseudo code in c++ but want to ask that Raptor's pseudo code is same like C++ and other languages or its different because Raptor work in flow charts
Here is the problem just give a little example of pseudo code for it Thanks
need help with writing pseudo code

Create and load an array with the following 7 values. Add one more word (of your own choosing) for a total of 8 words.

biff
comely
fez
mottle
peruke
bedraggled
quisling

Create a second array (parallel array). To hold the defintions to these words. You will need to look up the definitions.

- Be sure to use lowercase, as shown above. This will make the processing easier.
- Use an external .TXT file to load the words and the definitions into the arrays ( words.txt and definitions.txt).

Ask the user to enter a word

- Search through this array until you find a match with the word the user entered.
- Once you find a match, output "Yes, that word is in the dictionary" and output the definition.
- If you get to the end of the array and do NOT find a match, output "No, that word is not in the dictionary".
- The program should work with any set of words and definition in the arrays. If I were to change the words and definitions in the arrays, it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode isn't really language-specific. People often adopt the conventions of their target language to make their pseudocode align more closely with the way the language works, but the main idea is to get the high-level steps that the code should follow down on paper without worrying too much about the syntactic details. Since Raptor is a flowchart-based language, and since (like pseudocode) flowcharts are traditionally used to plan out how a program should work, a pseudocode description of a Raptor program should probably look like a flowchart, but without worrying about the details of Raptor's flowchart syntax.